# Python can't keep up with time

Tags: python, datetime, tuples

Can anybody explain the following?

```
timex = [2012, 3, 1]
epoch = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(*timex).utctimetuple())
date = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(epoch)
print date # [2012, 2, 29]

timex = [2012, 3, 15]
epoch = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime(*timex).utctimetuple())
date = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(epoch)
print date # [2012, 3, 14]
```

I'm not sure if it has to do with my misunderstanding of tuples, lists or time in general, but python is always a day behind :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting a time in UTC, but `datetime.date.fromtimestamp()` is converting it to local system time. You're west of UTC, setting the time to exactly midnight on a day, but your local time in e.g. Denver is the prior day.

Comment: Do you know of a way to ensure UTC is used?

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python it appears to be more complicated than I'd expected. I don't know of a better answer offhand, though.